# How to access a mapping in a library?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, library

```
library Lib{
    struct Data {
        mapping (uint => uint) a;
    }

    function inc(Data self) internal{
        self.a[0] =+1;
    }
}
contract Example{

    address recipient = 0x0000cafebabe;

    Lib.Data data;

    function send(){
        Lib.inc(data);
    }
}
```

Leads to error

```
7:9: Error: Member "a" is not available in struct Data memory outside of storage.
        self.a[0] =+1;
        ^----^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your code changed as below

```
function inc(Data storage self) internal{
        self.a[0]=+1;
    }
```

Note the `storage` part of it. Please understand the concepts of [Internal Types for variables](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#internal-types-for-libraries) and 
[In memory types](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#in-memory-types)

Comment: wow didn't know, need to check this Monday, must go to the F1 race with my father this tomorrow